# TypeError: expected a character buffer object with tuple passed to Python 2.4 str.endswith()

Tags: python, string-matching, python-2.4

My goal is to grab files with names ending with any item in `ext`.  I have the following code:

```
ext=["n.log",".shm","rage"]

for filename1 in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):  
    if filename1.endswith(tuple(ext)):         
          src=os.getcwd()+'/'+filename1  
          irun_log=os.path.basename(src)
```

Running this code with Python 2.4, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./compile", line 141, in ?
    if filename1.endswith(tuple(ext)):
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Any help to figure out this issue is appreciated.

Comment: So, it turns out that this is only an error with python-2.4.  I switch to python 2.7 and 3.5 and this error is gone and the code works.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to pass a tuple of strings to `str.endswith()` to was [introduced](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) in Python 2.5:

> **str.endswith**(*suffix*[, *start*[, *end*]])
>
> Return `True` if the string ends with the specified *suffix*, otherwise return `False`. *suffix* can also be a tuple of suffixes to look for. With optional *start*, test beginning at that position. With optional *end*, stop comparing at that position.
>
> *Changed in version 2.5:* Accept tuples as *suffix*.